# How to understand Drag-and-Drop Usage of a Web Application

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I want to build an automated tool that open's a website and just checks whether it is using drag and drop feature on it. For example, my tool is going to go through from list of different websites and if the website using drag and drop feature it is going to alert. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Is it possible? yes... but probably not worth the trouble.  You're going to have to check all the javascript code on the site as they might inject the event handlers or even grab all events from the body and check event targets.   Why di d you want to do this?

Comment: I just want to see how drag and drop is prevalent on the website.